# How to Get Deployer's Address (After contract is deployed)

Tags: solidity, ether

I have a function in my contract which is intended to receive ETH as follows

```
receive() external payable {

 uint256 amount = msg.value;        
 require(balanceOf(address(this)) >= amount, "Not enough tokens"); 
 
 /// Do stuff

}
```

The problem is when I try to send ETH, for some reason It is picking up the Sender's address instead of the deployer's wallet address to check for the `balanceOf` ERC20 token that address has. (MyEthWallet shows this message)

[image: Error]

I can confirm that the deployer's wallet has enough tokens

[image: Token amount]

How do I get the deployer's address without hardcoding it in my contract?

```
solidity version: pragma solidity ^0.8.9
local blockchain: Ganache v2.5.4 (truffle)
```

New to the blockchain, please bare with me :)

Comment: `address(this)` is the address of the smart contract receiving the funds. Deployer's address is not saved in the contract's storage by default (why would it be? 99% contracts don't need it). Store it yourself in the constructor if you need it.

Comment: This is what I am looking for but that does not seem to work, The `tokens` were transferred (on contract creation) from 0 address to the deplorer's wallet, hence the `address(this)` should work but it does not, it always gives me this error

Comment: You are confused about what you're trying to do. I suggest take a step back and understand the terms like "deployer" better.

Comment: yeah you are right, I did some more research, `address(this)` is the address of the current contract as you said and not the address of wallet who deployed the contract, I had it all wrong. I think below (Rodrigos reply) makes sense, I am trying to figure out how to add `_deployer` in the `constructor` to store the address of the wallet who deployed the contract

Comment: Ok so  you seem to be wrong, the deployer or the wallet which deployed the contract is stored in the storage and I can get it like the following `address deployer = owner(); `Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deployer address is the address of whom sent the contract to the blockchain, right?

You can do something like this in your contract:

```
constructor(address _deployer){
 deployer = _deployer;
}

address deployer;

function getDeployer() public view returns(address){
 return deployer;
}
```

But we need to figure out a little bit more of your intentions. You want to verify if the sender has enough balance in his wallet to perform the transaction?

If it's the case, then you should do something like this:

```
receive() external payable {

 uint256 amount = msg.value;
 address sender = msg.sender;        
 require(balanceOf(sender) >= amount, "Not enough tokens"); 
 
 /// Do stuff

}
```

There's also ne more thing. The function `balanceOf()` needs to be instanciated through an IERC20. Something like:

```
IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress)

receive() external payable {

 uint256 amount = msg.value;
 address sender = msg.sender;        
 require(token.balanceOf(sender) >= amount, "Not enough tokens"); 
 
 /// Do stuff

}
```

But since you are using payable modifier means that you want to receive ETH in that contract. In that case your function should be like:

```
receive() external payable {

 uint256 amount = msg.value;
 address sender = msg.sender;        
 require(sender.balance >= amount, "Not enough tokens"); 
 
 /// Do stuff

}

//IF YOU WANT TO KEEP WITH THE CONTRACT BALANCE 

receive() external payable {

 uint256 amount = msg.value;
 address self = address(this);        
 require(self.balance >= amount, "Not enough tokens"); 
 
 /// Do stuff

}
```

Please keep me posted. Does this help you?

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, the intention is to send ERC20 tokens (called PLOT in this example) to the sender when they send ETH to the contract address. So I am not checking `sender` balance but the balance of the wallet who holds ERC20 tokens to ensure it has enough tokens left to send back to the `sender` (where 1 Eth = 1 PLOT in this example). I cant use `self.balance` as that will try to check the balance of token on the contract? where Contract itself is not holding any ERC20 tokens, they were sent to the deplorer at the time contract was created.

Comment: Ok so I figured it out, the deployer or the wallet which deployed the contract is stored in the storage and I can get it like the following `address deployer = owner();` if I am using standard ERC20 ownable. Thanks for your help, I will mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

As the contract is already deployed there is no way to get the deployer's address by interacting with the smart contract. if it is in storage you can do the following to retrieve the storage data easily.

```
            await provider.getStorageAt(contractAddress, slotNumber);
```

If it is not in storage you can do the following in order to retrieve the deployer's address.

```
            const receipt = await ethers.provider.getTransactionReceipt(HASH_VALUE)
            console.log(receipt?.from)
```

If you can find the transaction hash either using the Ganache transaction or Ganache logs you can do the above to get the deployer address

```
            const currentBlock = await ethers.provider.getBlock("latest");
            let n = await ethers.provider.getTransactionCount(myAddr);
            loop1: for (let i = currentBlock.number; i >= 0 && (n > 0); --i) {
                try {
                    const block = await ethers.provider.getBlockWithTransactions(i);
                    if (block && block.transactions) {
                        for (const e of block.transactions) {
                            // when a contract is created to address is null
                            if (e.to == null) {
                                const receipt = await ethers.provider.getTransactionReceipt(e.hash)
                                // myAddr is the contract address that you have
                                if (receipt.contractAddress == myAddr) {
                                    console.log(receipt.from)
                                    break loop1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error("Error in block " + i, e);
                }
            }
```

if you can not find the transaction hash you can do the above. It loops thorough the blocks to till you find the transaction you need, with the transaction hashes the receipts are retrieved to get the from address that we need.

Comment: That might not be the relevant answer, I am not talking about client-side.

Comment: If you want to interact with the deployer owned tokens then you have to persist the deployer address in the contract itself. Better use `ownable` implementation. It will add security too.